# Load entire application at start up

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

I have a tabbed iOS application with each of the tabs having some sort of json request so the view loads ever so slightly slowly. I want to remove that lag completely so I'm wondering if there is a way to call the `ViewDidLoad` function from each of the classes during the login phase of the application.

```
if (login == "Success") {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        // Load all resources here

    }
}
```

I can understand this can be bad practice if the app is very large, but I think in this scenario the app isn't huge, but the lag between the view controllers is enough to be annoying. I would rather have the user wait at the start for 3-5 seconds whilst everything loads, and have a smooth experience once inside. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about you just add an `activityIndicator` showing the user that it's doing a json request, and do everything asynchronously, that'd feel better for the user

Comment: Activity indicator will just indicate it to the user though? Won't actually speed anything up?

Comment: Well doing a synchronous call before the app even starts would look like your app is slow-to-start and you wouldn't want your users to feel that way.

Comment: But if you really want it that way try doing this `someViewController.loadView()`

Comment: @Nouman there are plenty of apps that have a loading screen with a percentage complete bar before the main app is launched. Save all your json data in plist file and show it in viewcontrollers as needed. That would do it

Comment: @samB okay, how can I do that? Saving the data to the plist file?

Comment: @Nouman google my friend - https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=save+json+to+plist

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the lifecycle functions of the viewcontroller for yourself. The viewDidLoad function will be called when the view has been loaded.

> Apple: This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory.

So calling `let _ = viewController.view` will trigger the view creation and the call of this function.

But i think it's much better to have a startup phase instead. Think about a 'startup'-screen that downloads everything you need (with maybe a spinner and a text) and moves automatically to the content (the tabbar controller) when done. That may also fix the problem of a low network connectivity (think about a download that take a minute for example). You may display that screen modally above or as screen before the tabbbar controller.

If you don't like the idea of a startup phase you may also design your ui responsive. Start the download whenever needed / regularly and update your ui according to the results when ready. The ui will be fast then, but uses last known data. The meaningfulness and implementation depends on your content.

**Update**

On second thought: If you already have a server login screen, why not download the content directly after the successful download as part of the login? Users do not know if you are still checking the login or downloading some necessary data. You may say that login is only successful if server login AND download are finished successfully.